# Local variables, "dead code" and 2D arrays problems in Java

Tags: java, arrays, local

I'm having a few problems while developing the following code in Java:

```
setPos(x, y);
for (int i = 0; x < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; y < size; j++) {
        if (board[x][y] == 'K')
        {
            System.out.println("You've found a key! CONGRATS!");
            return true;
        }
```

Eclipse notice me that `i` and `j`, as local variables, they're not used : `The value of the local variable i is not used` . If I change the `i` and write the `x` instead, it tells me that I'm repeating the variable.

`j++` is tagged as `dead code` ?

Also, I have to search for a concrete type of element on the diagonal of a bidimensional array, I've been trying this with 2 for loops, as above, but no result yet.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Your exit condition `if (board[x][y] == 'K')` does not depend on `i` or `j`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Eclipse notice me that `i` and `j`, as local variables, they're not used

That's because you're not using them. You've assigned them values, and you've later incremented (added to) those values, but you've never *used* them for anything.

> `j++` is tagged as "dead code" (?)

For the same reason, the code increments the value of `j`, but `j` is never used, so the code does nothing. "Dead code" refers to code that has no purpose or which is never run.

---

Your loops don't make a lot of sense. For instance:

```
for (int i = 0; x < size; i++) {
```

Normally with a `for` loop, the control variable (`i` in this case) should appear in **all three** of the parts of the `for` statement (the initializer, the test, and the increment), like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
// Change here -^
```

But you're not doing that, you're only using `i` in the initializer and the increment, never in the test (`x < size`). The same is true of your loop with `j`.

Similarly, unless there's something changing the value of `x`, `y`, and/or `size`, then your loops will either never run (because `x` or `y` is already `>= size`), run *once* (because it happens that `board[x][u] == 'K'`), or they'll run forever (because `x` or `y` is `< size` and since nothing changes that, they just keep looping...).

Comment: I've just included the condition inside the method, so x and y can't be greater than size, so the for loop is not needed anymore. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
setPos(x, y);
        if (board[x][y] == 'K')  //no i or j so they are unused. 
        {
            System.out.println("You've found a key! CONGRATS!");
            return true;
        }
```

---

`If I change the i and write the x instead, it tells me that I'm repeating the variable.`

Because x is already a variable(your function argument).so you can't declare it again.

`dead code` : Code that has no effect on programme.[Dead code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code)

---

Note:it's not a solution of your problem(because i don't know). it is just to show you the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is giving you a hint where the error is:

```
for (int i = 0; x < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; y < size; j++) {
```

you iterate over `i` and `j`, but you specify `x < size` and `y < size` as a condition. Thus you never actually use the `i` and `j` value, thus `j++` and `i++` is dead code.

If you really would like to use a loop, you should use the variable you use for iteration in the for-loop's condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // i instead of x
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { // j instead of y
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I have to search for a concrete type of element on the diagonal of a bidimensional array, I've been trying this with 2 for loops, as above, but no result yet.

Why not use a single `for` loop, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< size; i++)
    if(board[i][i] == 'K')
    {
        System.out.println("You've found a key! CONGRATS!");
        return true;
    }
```